# JavaScript Firebase Login Integration: Uncaught ReferenceError: signIn is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying to make a sign-in form that is integrated with Firebase via JavaScript from https://gist.github.com/deltaepsilon/3b79aac7563cd8e55fa277913bede265.

However, I'm getting an Uncaught ReferenceError when I load the html file with Brackets and try clicking on the login button.

```
<div id="container">

    <form id="app">

        <div class="line"> 
            <label for="password">Email</label>
            <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" class="focus"/>
        </div>

        <div class="line">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" class="focus"/>
        </div>

        <div class="line submit">
            <a class="button" id="login" onClick="signIn"> Log In </a>
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

And the JavaScript part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {

        var app = document.querySelector('#app');

        app.signIn = function() {

            var email    = app.email;
            var password = app.password;

            if(!email || !password) {
                return console.log('email and password required');
            }

            // Signs in user.
            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .catch(function(error) {
                // Handles errors.
                    var errorCode = error.code;
                    var errorMsg  = error.message;
                    console.log('sign in error', error);
                });

        };
    })();
</script>
```

What's the issue? querySelector looks for something with 'app' as its id right? So onClick="signIn", since it is in 'app', should be able to call "signIn" onclick?

Sorry for my terseness -- I'm really new to web-dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the `signIn` function is not available globally. When you use it as `onClick="signIn"` it will search for the global `window` object for a function named `signIn` which is not defined -- `signIn` is defined in the `app` object.

You can set the `signIn` function to `window` object: `window.signIn = function() { ... }`.

Or use `addEventListener` to attach the event listener instead of using `onClick` in html:

```
document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", function(){
    // Code to sign-in 
});
```

Comment: For other methods, such as the firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged, how would that be rewritten using an eventListener?

Comment: Those are methods provided by the Firebase library. You can use `addEventListener` to listen to DOM events only.